# variables which type is account_name is shown as integer since Dawn4.1, while it is string in Dawn4.0

Tags: account-name, integer, string

Also if my action have an account_name param, it will ask for an integer too.
Is it right?

The following is what I post in telegram channel.

> Hi guys, my table's account field is shown/passed as an integer since EOS4.1. While, it is taken as string in EOS4.0. and the type is account_name in it's abi :

```
{
    "name": "account",
    "type": "account_name"
}
```

Now it is shown in this format :

```
cleos get table adv adv credit

{
  "rows": [{
      "account": "7306298747036631040", // in Dawn4.0 it is account's name string
      "adv_asset": "123.0000 ADV",
      "eos_asset": "0.0000 SYS"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this version has broken my contracts too. The solution is to change your parameters from `account_name` to simple plain `name`. It works like before! ;) They did that, afaik, to improve the `abi` files patterns.

Comment: How to convert `name` to `account_name`, if I want to save an `account_name` field but the parameter was `name`?